# Installation of j2sdk 1.4.2_09 on redhat machine

Tags: java, linux, redhat

I am working on a project which uses j2sdk 1.4.2_09. Previously, we were using Solaris machines to host the server. We are going to deprecate Solaris and want to move the Server to a Linux machine. I downloaded j2sdk 1.4.2_09 for Linux and then tried to install it on a 64 bit redhat machine. It failed giving the following error

"./j2sdk-1_4_2_09-linux-ia64-rpm.bin: line 395: ./install.sfx.17803: cannot execute binary file"

I tried installing the 32 bit version and got the following error.

"./j2sdk-1_4_2_09-linux-i586-rpm.bin: ./install.sfx.18137: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory"

Can somebody tell me how I should proceed.

Thanks,
Sajo

Answer (score 2):

Your redhat machine is probably x86_64, not ia64, so try to get that RPM.

By the way, you should really try to use an up-to-date version of Java. 1.4 is no longer supported and is probably insecure. Sun/Oracle go to great lengths to ensure backward compatibility.

Comment: Yes my machine is x86_64. I couldn't find a rpm for that. Could you please point me to that

Comment: It doesn't look like they made an RPM for it... Maybe try installing 1.7 and using the 1.4 RT as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue:

```
./j2sdk-1_4_2_09-linux-i586-rpm.bin: ./install.sfx.18137: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When installing `j2sdk-1_4_2_09-linux-i586-rpm.bin`, you need to install glibc (32bits).
In CentOS/RHEL 5/6 is:

```
 yum install glibc.i686
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on a project which uses j2sdk 1.4.2_09.

Use:

- The *latest* SDK  (e.g. version 7)
- An `rt.jar` of the target J2SE version
- The [cross-compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#crosscomp-options)

  1. `-source`
  2. `-target`
  3. **`-bootclasspath`**  (That is where the `rt.jar` is specified)

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to install the required java version.